# Получается дыра, при просмотре с большого экрана

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: скриншот №1]

[скриншот №2 ( все нормально при разрешении 1199 и ниже. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e30zw.jpg)

[image: после добавления]

Сайт не мой, сам новичок в этом, не могу понять , что происходит.
Версия `bootstrap :  v3.3.7` 
Если разрешение экрана больше чем `1199` , то вёрстка ломается и появляется свободное пространство. Если ниже разрешение, то нормально всё ( скриншот 2)
Кто может помочь?

После того как я добавил :

```html
.service-top-area{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Вот ссылка на сайт: http://nord-int.ru/index

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- service start -->
<section id="cens">
  <section class="service-area">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row service-top-area">
        <h1 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 39px;
    font-weight: 250;
">Условия приобретения, доставки и монтажа оборудования</h1>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.12s">
          <div class="single-service">

            <img src="img/icons/bank.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">

            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">ГАРАНТИЯ</h3>
            <p>Гарантийный и послегарантийный сервис.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.13s">
          <div class="single-service">

            <img src="img/icons/settings.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">
            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">МОНТАЖ</h3>
            <p>Монтаж оборудования осуществляется специалистами нашей компании.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.14s">
          <div class="single-service">

            <img src="img/icons/delivery-truck.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">

            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">ДОСТАВКА</h3>
            <p>Доставка осуществляется в любые регионы РФ.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.16s">
          <div class="single-service">
            <img src="img/icons/phone-receiver.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">

            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">ТЕХ.ПОДДЕРЖКА</h3>
            <p>Постоянная техническая поддержка 24/7</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.18s">
          <div class="single-service">
            <img src="img/icons/mail.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">
            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">ПОДБОР ОБОРУДОВАНИЯ</h3>
            <p>Широкий ассортимент учебного оборудования. Большая база производителей.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
          <div class="single-service">
            <img src="img/icons/customer-service.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">
            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ СПЕЦИАЛИСТА</h3>
            <p>Позвоните, если вам нужна консультация и вы не знаете точно, что вам нужно: менеджеры расскажут обо всем, что вас интересует, и помогут сделать заказ, наш телефон <a href="tel:+7963237823" style="
    color: #d8e2ee;
">+7-963-23-78-23</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
</section>
<!-- service End -->
```

Comment: Мало понятно, прикрепите действиющий пример который сможет повторить проблему или ссылку на сайт

Comment: Текст "Доставка осуществляется в любые регионы РФ" слишком короткий и третий блок получается слишком низким, что смещает следующую строку. Добавьте текста или увеличте высоту блока. Ну или задайте блокам `min-height'

Comment: @DmitryKozlov не могли бы вы подсказать куда добавлять ? именно к блоку " Доставка" или же к тем, которые ускакали ? да и если я просто добавляю в <style> , ничего не происходит, добавляю   min-height: 100px; 
Буду рад ответу, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если выставить фиксированную высоту блоков, то маленькое кол-во текста не будет смещать их при изменении размера

```css
.single-service {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 50px 0;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- service start -->
<section id="cens">
  <section class="service-area">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row service-top-area">
        <h1 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 39px;
    font-weight: 250;
">Условия приобретения, доставки и монтажа оборудования</h1>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.12s">
          <div class="single-service">

            <img src="img/icons/bank.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">

            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">ГАРАНТИЯ</h3>
            <p>Гарантийный и послегарантийный сервис.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.13s">
          <div class="single-service">

            <img src="img/icons/settings.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">
            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">МОНТАЖ</h3>
            <p>Монтаж оборудования осуществляется специалистами нашей компании.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.14s">
          <div class="single-service">

            <img src="img/icons/delivery-truck.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">

            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">ДОСТАВКА</h3>
            <p>Доставка осуществляется в любые регионы РФ.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.16s">
          <div class="single-service">
            <img src="img/icons/phone-receiver.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">

            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">ТЕХ.ПОДДЕРЖКА</h3>
            <p>Постоянная техническая поддержка 24/7</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.18s">
          <div class="single-service">
            <img src="img/icons/mail.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">
            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">ПОДБОР ОБОРУДОВАНИЯ</h3>
            <p>Широкий ассортимент учебного оборудования. Большая база производителей.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
          <div class="single-service">
            <img src="img/icons/customer-service.png" alt="" style="
    width: 100px;
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
">
            <h3 style="
    text-align:  center;
    font-size: 20px;
">КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ СПЕЦИАЛИСТА</h3>
            <p>Позвоните, если вам нужна консультация и вы не знаете точно, что вам нужно: менеджеры расскажут обо всем, что вас интересует, и помогут сделать заказ, наш телефон <a href="tel:+7963237823" style="
    color: #d8e2ee;
">+7-963-23-78-23</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
</section>
<!-- service End -->
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что сейчас ржут надо мной, но я ничего не понял, вы прикрепили выше кода фрагмент кода, он уже участвовал в коде ниже или нет ? я просто,действительно не понимаю, куда и что вставлять и честно , я ничего не хочу оставлять, а просто сказали исправить, сижу и ломаю голову в течении всего дня!

Comment: в класс `.single-service` я добавил `height: 200px;`

Comment: Если вы добавили, то ничего не произошло :( 
Я добавил ваш код .single-service {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 50px 0;
    height: 200px;
}
Прикреплю что произошло ( теперь вовсе не знаю, что это)

Comment: Скриншот прикрепил

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Вы были правы, если добавить больше текста, то все норм. Но мне все также  интересно, куда и что вставлять нужно было, было бы здорово, если бы объяснили! Жду ответа, спасибо вам!

Comment: Ну если добавили текста, то тоже норм. Главное чтобы блоки были примерно одинаковые по высоте.

Comment: Я так и не понял , как их выровнять через слить, который вы скинули, но думаю, в дальнейшем, при схожей ситуацию , уже буду хотяб знать куда двигаться, еще раз благодарность за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых нужно навести порядок в html и css!

Второе, рассыпаются блоки по причине их разной высоты. Решение - либо задать фикс. высоту для блоков, либо размещать по 3 колонки в каждом `.row`.

Еще решение с flex ( !лучше вообще перейти уже на [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)):

```css
h3 {
  font-size:20px;
}

a {
  color: #d8e2ee;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  display:  block;
  margin:  auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 39px;
  font-weight: 250;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  
  
}

.single-service {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
<div id="cens">
  <section class="service-area">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Условия приобретения, доставки и монтажа оборудования</h1>

      <div class="row service-top-area">
        
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.12s">
          <div class="single-service">

            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/HTML5_logo_black.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_black.svg.png" alt="" >

            <h3 >ГАРАНТИЯ</h3>
            <p>Гарантийный и послегарантийный сервис.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.13s">
          <div class="single-service">

            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/HTML5_logo_black.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_black.svg.png" alt="" >
            <h3>МОНТАЖ</h3>
            <p>Монтаж оборудования осуществляется специалистами нашей компании.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.14s">
          <div class="single-service">

            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/HTML5_logo_black.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_black.svg.png" alt=""  >

            <h3>ДОСТАВКА</h3>
            <p>Доставка осуществляется в любые регионы РФ.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.16s">
          <div class="single-service">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/HTML5_logo_black.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_black.svg.png" alt="" >

            <h3>ТЕХ.ПОДДЕРЖКА</h3>
            <p>Постоянная техническая поддержка 24/7</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.18s">
          <div class="single-service">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/HTML5_logo_black.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_black.svg.png" alt="" >
            <h3>ПОДБОР ОБОРУДОВАНИЯ</h3>
            <p>Широкий ассортимент учебного оборудования. Большая база производителей.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
          <div class="single-service">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/HTML5_logo_black.svg/512px-HTML5_logo_black.svg.png" alt="">
            <h3>КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ СПЕЦИАЛИСТА</h3>
            <p>Позвоните, если вам нужна консультация и вы не знаете точно, что вам нужно: менеджеры расскажут обо всем, что вас интересует, и помогут сделать заказ, наш телефон <a href="tel:+7963237823">+7-963-23-78-23</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
<!-- service End -->
```

Задать обертке:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: stretch;
```

Блоки выравниваются по оси Х  и растягиваются на высоту наибольшей колонки в строке.

Comment: Вау, спасибо большое за объяснение, а можно как-нибудь перейти на новую версию безболезненно? Просто сам действительно новичок в этом, понимаю, есть, но думаю, что если перейду, сайт упадет и уже я ничего не сделаю :( Ведь все висит на мне.

Comment: тогда постепенно внедряйте флекс))), потому что действительно что-то может поломаться

Answer (score 1):

Если содержимое ячеек будет меняться, то из-за фиксированной высоты содержимое может не влезть в блок и ваша верстка "поедет". 3-ий бутсрап сверстан на флоатах, если высота не статична, то поток нужно очищать с помощью `.clearfix`. Если относительная ширина колонки меняется от брейкпоинта, то [клеарфиксу](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-responsive-resets) можно добавить класс, [отвечающий за отображение на нужной ширине](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities-classes).

Answer (score -1):

Можно исправить это так

```
.service-top-area{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

А блок `h1` вынести за класс `service-top-area`. На странице много `h1` тегов, исправь это. Максимум должен быть только 1 элемент `h1`.

Comment: зато ползет на маленьком (мобильном) разрешении

Comment: @DmitryKozlov на малых разрешениях нужно добавить строчку justify-content: center; и внутренним блокам задать 100% width